# TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

help ;-;

```
PS D:\Files\Berinon\utils> node .
D:\Files\Berinon\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:544
      throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');
      ^

TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (D:\Files\Berinon\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:544:13)
    at new Client (D:\Files\Berinon\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:73:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Files\Berinon\utils\index.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
}
```

this is the error that I got after changing Discord.client to Discord.Client. I just knew that .client is defined as any. not near on being a constructer like .Client.
If anyone wants to know the code, here it is.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"]});

const mongoose = require('mongoose')


require('dotenv').config();

client.queue = new Map();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();

['command_handler', 'event_handler'].forEach(handler =>{
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord)
})

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_SRV, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    userFindAndModify: false,
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Succesfully connected to MongoDB')
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```